# Loading iptables rules at boot

Tags: iptables, boot, restore, rules, fedora-22

i have added some rules to the iptables.

I saved the iptables rules using the command

> iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables

To apply the rules i did

> systemctl start iptables.service

When i type the below command,it shows the rules.

> iptables -L -n -v

Again to make sure that they load in the boot up i did the following.

> systemctl enable iptables.service

The problem is once i reboot the machine, the rules which i saved doesn't boot. What could be the problem here ?

When i open the iptables file my rules are listed there. If i manually type the command

> iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables

then the rules get added to the iptables

By the way i am using fedora 22.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent fedora releases use firewalld and not iptables. The configuration is located at: /etc/firewalld

Read the official [guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD) here

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got it working by disabling firewalld and re-enabling iptables.